# Tomcat Configuration with openssl Failed

Tags: ssl, https, tomcat, openssl

I am trying  to configure Tomcat  with openssl (ssl ). I have generated Keystore by name serverde**.jks

My config With server.xml Is:

```
      <Connector  port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" 
               keystoreFile="/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/serverdestkey.jks" 
               keyAlias="tomcat1" keystorePass="*****" clientAuth="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"  SSLEnabled="true" />
```

I used same certificate for apache2 server with specific application, which works fine.
But when I try to config same certificate with tomcat using keystore fail to work. tomcat is running successfully but, when i tried access with url page not found error occurs.

Even I cannot access url with normal connector(non-ssl -> http)

```
<Connector port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

MY log

```
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.37
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 12 2018 12:07:02 UTC
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.37.0
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-142-generic
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/jre
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_80-b15
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37
    07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37
07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.775 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.787 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.817 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 808 ms
07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.37
07-Feb-2019 12:47:58.874 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/docs]
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.450 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/docs] has finished in [575] ms
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.450 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/ROOT]
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.488 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [38] ms
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.488 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/manager]
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.533 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/manager] has finished in [45] ms
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.533 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/host-manager]
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.563 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [30] ms
07-Feb-2019 12:47:59.563 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/examples]
07-Feb-2019 12:48:00.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/samba/restricted/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/examples] has finished in [447] ms
07-Feb-2019 12:48:00.026 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
07-Feb-2019 12:48:00.035 INFO [main] 

org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1217 ms
```

Comment: Did you add also the key (not only certificate)?

Comment: Yeah I have added..

Comment: have you try to access the site with `openssl` command?

Comment: No how to access.. Im new to this

Comment: I cannot access url with 8085 port with not using ssl @RomeoNinov

Comment: For SSL try command like: `openssl s_client -connect your_IP:8443` And you can't access http because it redirect to https

Comment: Thanks@RomeoNinov I dont want SSL. I cannot run with normal  http .. Please educate me

Comment: connect timeout .. Not connect  -->openssl s_client -connect your_IP:8443@RomeoNinov

Comment: Solved .. firewall issue forget to allow  ufw -->   ufw allow 8443

Comment: If it was a firewall issue then you did *not* get a "page not found" error, but a timeout. Please be precise in your question, it makes finding a solution much easier.